# How to count longest uninterrupted sequence of dates

Tags: python, date, datetime, sequence

I know how to count the longest uninterrupted sequence looking like

```
list = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Now I'm trying to to this with a list of dates like

```
date1 = datetime.date(2021, 5, 11) 
date2 = datetime.date(2021, 5, 12) 
date3 = datetime.date(2021, 5, 18) 
date4 = datetime.date(2021, 5, 19) 
date5 = datetime.date(2021, 5, 20)
date6 = datetime.date(2021, 5, 25) 
date7 = datetime.date(2021, 5, 26)  

date_list = [date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, date6, date7]
```

I'm looking for the longest uninterrupted sequence of days. I tried to translate the sequence of days into something like the first list, with 1 for just 1 day difference (uninterrupted) and 0 for more than one day difference (interrupted), but so far I couldn't come up with a solution at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assuming it's sorted

```
longest_start_index = 0
longest_end_index = 0
current_start_index = 0
current_end_index = 0
curr_date = date_list[0]

while (current_end_index < len(date_list)):
    next_date = date_list[current_end_index]
    if (next_date-curr_date).days > 1:
        # next day is more than 1 day away so reset start index
        current_start_index = current_end_index
    else:
        if (current_end_index - current_start_index) > (longest_end_index - longest_start_index):
            longest_start_index = current_start_index
            longest_end_index = current_end_index
    current_end_index = current_end_index + 1
    curr_date = next_date

print(f'Longest continuous sequence is from {date_list[longest_start_index]} to {date_list[longest_end_index]}')
```